# Use typescript to create Closure/Class using 'new' keyword with callable instance and accessible properties

Tags: typescript, class, properties, closures, callable

I am trying to create a class/closure called `MyRequest` which should work as described below:

```
const myRequest = new MyRequest()

console.log(myRequest.hasBeenCalled) // false

myRequest()

console.log(myRequest.hasBeenCalled) // true
```

Is it possible to accomplish this? Can a function/method have accessible properties like this?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html

Comment: Class instances aren't really designed to be callable, and TypeScript's typings for classes don't make it easy.  Having `MyRequest` be a regular function would be easier.  Anyway, [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqQGkm) is how to do it both ways.  If you want me to write up an answer explaining it, I can.  Otherwise, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Great answer! I did not know you could write { (): void } in types/interfaces! Feel free to write up the answer, preferably the one using the 'new' keyword:) I think I owe you a cup of coffee jcalz :-)